# How to force laptop mode on/off

Tags: linux, power-management, laptop-mode

```
root@vi-notebook:/home/vi# laptop_mode start force
Laptop mode 
enabled, not active
```

How to start laptop mode? It starts successfully when AC adapter is removed, but not by explicit command.

The system is GNU/Linux Debian i386 squeeze (not up to date), 2.6.30-zen2-31270-gc7099db-dirty, Acer Extensa 5220.

**Update:**
Changed to `ENABLE_LAPTOP_MODE_ON_AC=1 in /etc/laptop_mode/laptop-mode.conf`, now it is turned on always. But I can't turn it off with `laptop_mode stop force`, it stays turned on anyway.

How do I turn it off again?

**Update 2:**
Implemented hardcore solution, "radical laptop mode": http://vi-server.org/vi/code/kernel/0003-block-Introduce-hung-iosched.patch

It just forces HDD to be off until I explicitly allow access to it again (all requests get hung).

Comment: Changed to ENABLE_LAPTOP_MODE_ON_AC=1 in /etc/laptop_mode/laptop-mode.conf, now it is turned on always. But I can't turn it off with "laptop_mode stop force", it stays turned on anyway.

Comment: @vi - You should edit your question instead of adding information in the comment field, makes it easier to read.

Comment: Well if "ENABLE_LAPTOP_MODE_ON_AC=1" works on then just reverse when you want it off "ENABLE_LAPTOP_MODE_ON_AC=0"